# Issue adding rows to DOM table on MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a "DOM" list in MVC 4 using jQuery to add elements dynamically but at the moment of removing all the elements
The table no longer allows me to add more elements, I have tried to use length and comparisons but it does not work.

Am probably missing something obvious but can't see what it is. Any ideas?

Example

[image]

Here is my table code

```
    <div><a href="#" id="addNew"><img src="~/Images/splus.png" alt="Add Product" style="border:0"/></a></div>
        <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
               <th>Product</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
            {
                int j = 0;
                int index = 1;
                foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                   <tr>
                        <td>@index</td>
                        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(a => a[j].SEQ_NO, new { id = "nrow", Value = index })</td>
                        <td>@Html.DropDownList("PRODUCTS", "Select Product")</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].QUANTITY)</td>                 
                        <td>   
                                <a href="#" id="remove" class="remove"><img src="~/Images/sminus.png" alt="Add Product" style="border:0"/></a>    
                        </td>                      
                   </tr>
                    index += 1;
                    j++;
                }
            }
         </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here is my jQuery Code when i click on Add New

```
            $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var last = $('#dataTable>tbody>tr:last');
            if (last.length > 0) {
                var name = last.children().find('input,select')[0].name;
                var index = Number(name.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')) + 1;
                var tr = ('<tr>' + last.html().replace(/[0-9]+__/gi, index + '__') + '</tr>').replace(/\[[0-9]+\]+[.]/gi, '[' + index + '].');
                numberRows($('#dataTable tbody').append(tr));
             }

            });
```

UPDATE:

Add "REMOVE CODE"

```
            $(document).on('click', '#remove', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            numberRows($('#dataTable tbody'));

        });
```

Comment: You need to either a) don't allow `tr:last` to be deleted (hide the delete button on `tr:first`) or b) store your row template elsewhere - on a hidden tr or on a different, hidden table

Comment: @freedomn-m How can i delete or hidden delete button only on the first row using my remove code?

Comment: In your css: `table>tbody>tr:first>td>a.remove { display:none; }`

Comment: Or hide the whole row so that it's always a template: `table>tbody>tr:first { display:none; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am probably missing something obvious but can't see what it is. Any ideas?

`var name = last.children().find('input,select')[0].name;`

This line of code requires one last  child, which means after you removed the last  under , the `name` will be undefined. In fact, the Add New function won’t even pass the `if (last.length > 0)` since when the last  got removed, the `last.length` becomes 0.

You can debug in devtools, and will see:

BEFORE the last  got removed:

[image]

AFTER the last  got removed:

[image]

Thus, to fix this issue, the simplest solution is to not remove the last  but hide it. Please check below code:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#remove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#dataTable>tbody>tr').length > 1) {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            //numberRows($('#dataTable tbody'));
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        }
    });
```

Ps. Not sure what happens in numberRows() function so I commented it.

Comment: Works like a charm! for answering until now

Comment: I got an error when save my data to DB "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." This error is shown when I delete all the elements and rebuild the DOM list, it happens when I press the submit button